# Converting a Date Time Field to Another Time Zone and add a new colunm in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, timezone

Please show me how to convert a Date Time to Another Time Zone and add a new colunm in Python.

I am not very sure about the exact timezone of the original data (Maybe is AEST) but  I need a new coulmn that is - 17 Hours than the original one (should be California time).

Like this picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCwUL.png

Thank you!

Comment: Images of data is not optimal for people to help you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) also [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that you have a dataframe like this:

```
    time
0   1597101380360
1   1597099168350
2   1597095668690
3   1597085316180
4   1597054931440
```

And you know for sure that the time zone is 'Australia/Queensland'

First, let's get the time converted to a readable format and save it in a new column called **date_time**:

```py
df['date_time']= pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='ms',origin='unix'
                                      ).apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
```

Now the dataframe looks like this:

```
         time            date_time
0   1597101380360   2020-08-10 23:16:20
1   1597099168350   2020-08-10 22:39:28
2   1597095668690   2020-08-10 21:41:08
3   1597085316180   2020-08-10 18:48:36
4   1597054931440   2020-08-10 10:22:11
```

Now, before we change the timezone, we need to associate the date_time with the original timezone the timestamp was created, for that we use the [tz_localize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) function. Then we create a new column called **cali_time** applying the function [astimezone(timezone())](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/)  to save the datetime with the new timezone:

```py
#assigning timezone to date_time
df['date_time']= df.date_time.dt.tz_localize('Australia/Queensland')
#creating new column with time zone set to US/Pacific 
df['cali_time']=df.date_time.dt.tz_convert('US/Pacific')
df.head()
```

Now the dataframe looks like this:

```
        time                 date_time                  cali_time
0   1597101380360   2020-08-10 23:16:20+10:00   2020-08-10 06:16:20-07:00
1   1597099168350   2020-08-10 22:39:28+10:00   2020-08-10 05:39:28-07:00
2   1597095668690   2020-08-10 21:41:08+10:00   2020-08-10 04:41:08-07:00
3   1597085316180   2020-08-10 18:48:36+10:00   2020-08-10 01:48:36-07:00
4   1597054931440   2020-08-10 10:22:11+10:00   2020-08-09 17:22:11-07:00
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mel, That's very detailed!

But when I try the first code: df['date_time']= pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='ms',origin='unix'
                                      ).apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))

The time was converted to 1970-01-19 while it should be 2020-8-xx (time:1598128447)

Could you please tell me how can I fix this?

Comment: can you provide a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: Both `lambda`s and the `pytz` import are not necessary. You can directly call strftime on a column and convert to another timezone using `dt.tz_convert`.

Comment: @Elena_w try it this way:  df['date_time']= pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='s').apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))